# Adjust color based on contrast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, accessibility

For a mod I'm working on, I'd like to incorporate the player's theme colors and use them to generate UI elements. However, I'm running into an issue where not all color themes have colors that provide a [good contrast ratio](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum) as outlined in *[1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum)* of *[Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/)*.

I can currently check the contrast with the following:

```
float RelativeLuminance(Color color)
{
    float ColorPartValue(float part)
    {
        return part <= 0.03928f ? part / 12.92f : Mathf.Pow((part + 0.055f) / 1.055f, 2.4f);
    }
    var r = ColorPartValue(color.r);
    var g = ColorPartValue(color.g);
    var b = ColorPartValue(color.b);

    var l = 0.2126f * r + 0.7152f * g + 0.0722f * b;
    return l;
}

private float ColorContrast(Color a, Color b)
{
    float result = 0f;
    var La = RelativeLuminance(a) + 0.05f;
    var Lb = RelativeLuminance(b) + 0.05f;

    result = Mathf.Max(La, Lb) / Mathf.Min(La, Lb);

    return result;
}
```

I use the found color contrast to determine whether or not the initial text color is good enough.

```
public Color GetContrastingColors(Color backgroundColor, Color textColor)
{
    Color contrastColor;

    // See if we have good enough contrast already
    if (!(ColorContrast(backgroundColor, textColor) < 4.5f))
    {
        return textColor;
    }

    Color.RGBToHSV(textColor, out var textH, out var textS, out var textV);
    Color.RGBToHSV(backgroundColor, out var bgH, out var bgS, out var bgV);

    // Modify textV by some value to provide enough contrast.

    contrastColor = Color.HSVToRGB(textH, textS, textV);

    return contrastColor;
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to adjust the colors so that the text color just brightens (or dims) enough to get to that 4.5:1 contrast ratio. Originally, I was thinking of working the algebra for the luminosity and contrast equations to the point where the `sRGB` values are multiplied by some value X. I remembered HSV though, and adjusting the brightness of the color seems a lot simpler to me. The issue is, I'm unsure how to compare the contrasts of 2 HSV colors, let alone use their values to manipulate a color's brightness to reach a desired contrast.

My current thought process is to do something dumb like this:

```
float targetL;
bool brighter = false;
var backL = RelativeLuminance(backgroundColor);
var textL = RelativeLuminance(textColor);
var ratio = 4.5f;

// Try to go in the direction of brightness originally.
if (textL > backL)
{
    targetL = ((backL + 0.05f) * ratio) - 0.05f;
    brighter = true;

    if (targetL > 1f)
    {
        targetL = ((backL + 0.05f) / ratio) - 0.05f;
        brighter = false;
    }
}
else
{
    targetL = ((backL + 0.05f) / ratio) - 0.05f;
    if (targetL > 0f)
    {
        targetL = ((backL + 0.05f) * ratio) - 0.05f;
        brighter = true;
    }
}

Color adjustedColor = textColor;

while ((!brighter && textL > targetL) || (brighter && textL < targetL))
{
    Color.RGBToHSV(adjustedColor, out var textH, out var textS, out var textV);

    textV += brighter ? 0.01f : -0.01f;

    adjustedColor = Color.HSVToRGB(textH, textS, textV);
    textL = RelativeLuminance(adjustedColor);
}

contrastColor = adjustedColor;
```

But that's not really efficient, so how can I manipulate the text color so that it "remains the same" but provides enough contrast?

Edit:

To give more context to what I'm trying to do, imagine I have the following set of 4 colors as the player's theme.

[image: 4 different shades of purple.]

In terms of HTML codes, that's:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| #32263d | #3d1c70 |
| #7347b6 | #320d68 |

I want to incorporate 2 of those colors from their theme when creating a UI for them. However, not all of them are easily distinguishable, you can see the various contrasts in this case here:

[image: 4 different shades of purple in rows with different numbers across each row in each of the other colors, indicating that colors contrast with it.]

Now each theme contains a darker and lighter color just like the center 2 rows in this example, but also like this example, their contrast may not always be accessible for the end user to read. Moving along with the example, in this case, we're going to be using `#32263d` and `#7347b6` to build our UI.

[image: The two colors side by side.]

While I could try to randomly create a shade of purple similar, I want to keep it as close to the original as possible and just brighten it. We can see how it'd look in the various levels of light, here:

[image: A gradient showing the various levels of lighting for #7347b6.]

If we set `#7347b6` to the maximum brightness at `#a163ff`, we get the following pair now:

[image: #32263d and #a163ff side by side.]

While better than before, this is only a contrast of 3.88 : 1 still. So now I want to scale down the brightness of `#32263d`. If we reduce it to `#251B2D`, we then end up with this:

[image: #251B2D and #a163ff side by side.]

The two new colors then have a color contrast of 4.51 : 1.

Now, I could go through each theme manually, but given the number of them, I'd prefer to write an algorithm that generates the updated colors on the fly.

Comment: _"I'd like to incorporate the player's theme colors and use them to generate UI elements. However, I'm running into an issue where not all color themes have colors that provide a good contrast ratio"_ - Are you talking about _["**Complementary** - Two colors that are on **opposite sides of the color wheel**. This combination provides a **high contrast** and high impact color combination – together, these colors will appear brighter and more prominent."](https://www.canva.com/colors/color-wheel/)?_

Comment: @MickyD No, I'm referring to a pair of colors in a player object's theme like `new Color(0.1647059f, 0.3098039f, 0.5843138f, 1f)` and `new Color(0.2196078f, 0.254902f, 0.3098039f, 1f)`. They are not complementary necessarily, nor do they tend to be so.

Comment: A quick look at [Adobe Color - Accessibility Tools - **Contrast Checker**](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-contrast-analyzer) suggests that your choices of `#2A4E95` and `#37414E` are better served by simply changing the _background_ colour to `#A8C5E9` instead.  This will achieve a contrast ratio of **4.5:1**.  It sounds like your problem is simply _how to calculate the accessibility background colour given a text colour_.   [Possibility relevant](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/107319/2275)

Comment: @MickyD "It sounds like your problem is simply how to calculate the accessibility background colour given a text colour." Yes/No. I could do that, but it's just the same issue in disguise (I still need to calculate the color based off another color). My issue is that I'm trying to maintain the "same" color, by simply only adjusting the brightness of it on an HSV scale (the same result as if I were to multiple the RGB components by a factor `x`). Changing either to `#A8C5E9` would actually adjust them differently from what I intend. (1/2)

Comment: To give an example, if I was given `#80b9ff` and `#5b6b80` (contrast ratio of 2.67), I'd want to lower `#5b6b80`'s brightness until it became `#505d70` (contrast ratio of 4.55 with `#80b9ff`). It still has the same hue and saturation, just a different brightness. Now, these colors I threw out there, are just a couple of the ones built into the game. I can't modify them, so I need to work with them.  My question is how can I adjust them for such? (2/2)

Comment: _"I'd want to lower ... brightness until it became ... (contrast ratio of 4.55 ). It still has the same hue and saturation, just a `different brightness`"_ - Maybe I missed something but I don't understand how your situation is different to any other accessibility issue.  I did plug your values into the Adobe tool mentioned above.  Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my answer for [Adapt given color pairs to adhere to W3C Accessibility standard for ePubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187918/adapt-given-color-pairs-to-adhere-to-w3c-accessibility-standard-for-epubs/70192373#70192373)

You can skip the part where I talk about the contrast ratio formula since you have that already but I talk about how to adjust the colors to get better contrast.

If I were to actually code my recommendation from the previous answer, I would be more efficient and rather than adding or subtracting 1 from each RGB component and recomputing the luminance, I would probably add/subtract 10 and recompute.  If not sufficient contrast, do 10 again.  Once I get enough contrast, I could then re-adjust the values, perhaps by 2 each time, in the opposite direction until I got as close to 4.5 without going under.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a loop after all for my code. While [slugolicious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70533189/9813161)'s answer was close to what I wanted, I found that adjust all the RGB components by the same amount was not what I wanted as is actually affected the hue, so I ended up using HSV instead.

```
public Color[] GetContrastingColors(Color backgroundColor, Color textColor, float ratio)
{
    Color[] colors = new Color[2];

    var backL = RelativeLuminance(backgroundColor);
    var textL = RelativeLuminance(textColor);

    if (textL > backL)
    {
        colors[0] = textColor;
        colors[1] = backgroundColor;
    }
    else
    {
        colors[1] = textColor;
        colors[0] = backgroundColor;
    }

    // See if we have good enough contrast already
    if (!(ColorContrast(backgroundColor, textColor) < ratio))
    {
        return colors;
    }

    Color.RGBToHSV(colors[0], out var lightH, out var lightS, out var lightV);
    Color.RGBToHSV(colors[1], out var darkH, out var darkS, out var darkV);

    // If the darkest color can be darkened enough to have enough contrast after brightening the color.
    if (ColorContrast(Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, 0f), Color.HSVToRGB(lightH, lightS, 1f)) >= ratio)
    {
        var lightDiff = 1f - lightV;
        var darkDiff = darkV;

        var steps = new float[] { 0.12f, 0.1f, 0.08f, 0.05f, 0.04f, 0.03f, 0.02f, 0.01f, 0.005f };
        var step = 0;

        var lightRatio = (lightDiff / (lightDiff + darkDiff));
        var darkRatio = (darkDiff / (lightDiff + darkDiff));

        while (ColorContrast(Color.HSVToRGB(lightH, lightS, lightV), Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, darkV)) < ratio)
        {
            while (ColorContrast(Color.HSVToRGB(lightH, lightS, lightV + lightRatio * steps[step]), Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, darkV - darkRatio * steps[step])) > ratio && step < steps.Length - 1)
            {
                step++;
            }
            lightV += lightRatio * steps[step];
            darkV -= darkRatio * steps[step];
        }

        colors[0] = Color.HSVToRGB(lightH, lightS, lightV);
        colors[1] = Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, darkV);
    }
    // Fall back to using white.
    else
    {
        colors[0] = Color.white;

        while (ColorContrast(Color.white, Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, darkV)) < ratio)
        {
            darkV -= 0.01f;
        }

        colors[1] = Color.HSVToRGB(darkH, darkS, darkV);
    }

    return colors;
}
```